LWC NavigationMixin throws an exception during navigate to custom page
I'm a little bit confused. Let's say we have this code
handleClick(e) {
    this.waitingForResult = true;
    try {
        switch(e.target.dataset.id) {
            case 'go2box' : 
                
                this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
                    type: 'standard__webPage',
                    attributes: {
                        url: `https://app.box.com/folder/${this.source.folderId}`,
                    }
                })
                .then(url => {
                    console.log('resolved');
                    window.open(url, "_blank");
                });
            // no need to wait for a page
                break;
         
        } 
    } catch(e) {
        console.log('error');
        console.log(e.message);
    }
}

it navigates us to expected page but in devconsole i always see

error
aura_prod.js:105 Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')

what have i done in wrong way?

[NavigationMixin.Navigate](pageReference) is meant to dispatch a navigation request, it opens a new page and returns undefined, so calling a method on it will lead to an exception.
If you want to generate a url to use it later you should use [NavigationMixin.GenerateUrl](pageReference) that returns a promise so you can use .then(url => { something }).
In your case, since you want to just open the url in a new tab, you could use NavigationMixin.GenerateUrl and keep the then
case 'go2box' : 
    this[NavigationMixin.GenerateUrl]({
        type: 'standard__webPage',
        attributes: {
            url: `https://app.box.com/folder/${this.source.folderId}`
        }
    })
    .then((url) => {
        window.open(url, '_blank');
    });

